# Ошибка "Входная строка имела неверный формат". C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь записать выбранное в combobox значение в БД. Конвертирую из строки в число, но выдает ошибку. Помоги разобраться в чем проблема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код

```
private void peremestit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((comboBox2.SelectedIndex != -1) && (comboBox3.SelectedIndex != -1))
            {
                var sel_in = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                var mesto = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
                 var inv_n = Convert.ToInt32(sel_in);
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE [dbo].[Sklad] SET Mesto_Hraneniya ='{mesto}' WHERE Invent_num = '{inv_n}'", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                GetList();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("problema");
            }
        }
```

Тип данных в БД.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код заполнения combobox.

```
void LoadInventarNomer()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * from [dbo].[Sklad]", con);
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(dataSet);

                comboBox2.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
                comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Invent_num";
                comboBox2.ValueMember = "Invent_num";

                comboBox2.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
                comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Invent_num";
                comboBox2.ValueMember = "Invent_num";
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ну, у вас студия остановилась, выдала ошибку на неверный формат. А причину так и не посмотрели. Что у вас в этот момент находится в `sel_in` и какой она тип имеет?

Comment: Тип System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: Поставьте `string` при объявлении переменной, не используйте `var`.

Comment: Поставил, не помогло

Comment: Что содержит переменная sel_in? Как вы заполняете комбобокс?

Comment: Эта переменная содержит в себе выбранный пользователем инвентарный номер. Заполняю  данными из таблицы в БД

Comment: Вы в отладчике когда ошибка возникает, что видите в этой переменной?

Comment: System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, код заполнения комбобокса.

Comment: @Dimanson добавил этот код в конце вопроса

Comment: Я решил эту проблему. Заменил строчку var sel_in = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();    на строчку   var sel_in = comboBox2.Text;

Comment: 1 Попробуйте забирать не таблицу. а только одно поле из таблицы - этот же код используется только для ComboBox? 2 В паре с ValueMember надо использовать SelectedValue, а не SelectedItem: var sel_in = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString(); ... наверное...